# UILocalNotification stop sound after notification is dismissed

Tags: uilocalnotification

I have an app that will set an alarm for the user.  The alarm is a basic UILocalNotification with a sound file that is 12 seconds long.  The sound plays on the device but it does not go away when the use dismisses the notification.  I got it to stop playing sound on the simulator by using this

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    UILocalNotification *localNotif = [launchOptions objectForKey:UIApplicationLaunchOptionsLocalNotificationKey];
    if (localNotif) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelLocalNotification:localNotif];
    }    
    return YES;
}
```

Any help would be great.

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I put this on my AppDelegate and it works.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{
    [UIApplication sharedApplication].applicationIconBadgeNumber = 0;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] cancelAllLocalNotifications];
}
```

Hope it help.

Comment: It did not work for me. :( The sound is still being played for the complete 30 second duration.

Comment: Why would you cancel all notifications? this is not a solution, and if it is, is a very bad one.