# The UILocalNotification sound does not stop playing

Tags: ios, iphone, audio, uilocalnotification

I have set a custom .aif 30 second file as the local notification sound name. And below is my code for scheduling the local notification.

```
//Function to schedule local notification
-(void)schedulelocalnotification:(NSDate *)particularfiredate ringtone: (NSString *)particularringtone name:(NSString *)alarmname info:(NSDictionary *)dicttext
{
UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = particularfiredate;
notification.soundName = [arrayAIFFFiles objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]];
notification.alertBody = alarmname;
notification.userInfo = dicttext;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

But when the device is locked, and the user slides on the notification to enter the app, the sound keeps on playing even when the user enters the app. It continues to play even when the user quits/uninstalls the app.
Please suggest what could be the possible reasons.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveLocalNotification:(UILocalNotification *)notification
{

    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:@"0" forKey:@"demo"];
    NSLog(@"%i",[[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduledLocalNotifications] count]);
    NSString *viewcontrollerstring = [notification.userInfo objectForKey:@"smiletosnooze"];
    NSLog(@"++++++------%@",viewcontrollerstring);


}
```

PS: I checked - [UILocalNotification stop sound after notification is dismissed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10143440/uilocalnotification-stop-sound-after-notification-is-dismissed) and this - [Stop UILocalNotification Sound on slide to view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24340423/stop-uilocalnotification-sound-on-slide-to-view) but it was of no help. :(

Comment: It seems there is a filed bug report for this... http://openradar.appspot.com/15901634

Comment: Does the sound stop if you press any of the device's hardware volume buttons?

Comment: Yes, the sound does stop when device hardware volume buttons are pressed. So now, if there is a bug report, does that mean there is no work around? As I can see few apps who are doing it - https://itunes.apple.com/en/app/alarm-clock-hd-free/id382604920?mt=8

How are they doing it?

Comment: One more question: Does this behaviour change depending on whether the iPhone is passcode locked or not?

Comment: Yes, I just tested applying the passcode, The notification sound stops when slided -when the passcode lock is on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be an open bug with iOS 7 as filed [here](http://openradar.appspot.com/15901634). It also seems that when a device is passcode-locked, this issue does not appear. A pretty ugly hack that worked for me is setting a value for the application badge number and removing it immediately when the app comes into foreground. A sample code would be:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 1];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];

}
```

**EDIT**:

Apparently, the above mentioned hack is not actually working on iOS 7.1+. The only work-around I found is the following, but I'm very hesitant in calling it an actual answer:

```
- (void)applicationWillEnterForeground:(UIApplication *)application
{
   AVAudioSession *session = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
   [session setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayback error:nil];
   [session setActive:YES error:nil];
   MPMusicPlayerController *musicPlayer = [MPMusicPlayerController applicationMusicPlayer];
    [musicPlayer setVolume:0.0f]; 
}
```

But there are a number of serious flaws with the code above:

1. `setVolume` method is deprecated since iOS 7 (although apparently many apps are still using it)
2. You have at some point of your app to re-set the volume to a proper (non-zero level)
3. Setting the volume property will most definitely have side-effects in other apps that might be playing sounds or music at the same time

**UPDATE September 18, 2014**

This issue seems to be resolved on iOS 8.

Comment: Tried this, but doesnt work. The sound still continues to play till 30 seconds i.e EOF.

Comment: @ScarletWitch yes, you are right, it doesn't work on iOS 7.1+... Check my edit above for a "work-around"

Comment: Thanks @spassas for the prompt reply and the effort, But it still doesnt work :( The device sound is muted (as I can see from the icon appearing), but the sound continues.

Comment: @ScarletWitch Strange, it seems to work fine on my iPhone 4S running iOS 7.1.1. I've added a few more lines to configure the `AVAudioSession`. I must admit that I can't think of anything else at the moment :)

Comment: Thanks a ton, @spassas, It works now. Though the watermark for sound keep appearing, but it works. (y)