# UILocalNotification sound run in a loop

Tags: ios, loops, uilocalnotification

I am having an aiff file of 5.0 seconds. I want to run it in loop up to 30 seconds. Please guide how could I do that. 
Right now I am setting the notification in the normal way by the following code-

```
//Function to schedule local notification
-(void)schedulelocalnotification:(NSDate *)particularfiredate ringtone: (NSString *)particularringtone name:(NSString *)alarmname info:(NSDictionary *)dicttext
{
    UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification.fireDate = particularfiredate;
    notification.soundName = [arrayAIFFFiles objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]];
    notification.alertBody = alarmname;
    notification.userInfo = dicttext;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
}
```

Please note that I don't want the notification banner and the notifications to appear 6 times, Just the sound should repeat up to 30 seconds.

If I am not doing this, And adding a sound file of 30 seconds, then the sound is continuous till 30 seconds, If the user closes the notification in between, and opens the app, The sound continues to play.That issue has been stated here : [The UILocalNotification sound does not stop playing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24527704/the-uilocalnotification-sound-does-not-stop-playing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it by creating multiple notifications at regular intervals which will be the duration of the track. Following is my code :

```
-(void)schedulelocalnotification:(NSDate *)particularfiredate ringtone: (NSString *)particularringtone name:(NSString *)alarmname info:(NSDictionary *)dicttext
{//post one single notification here with alert body, so that there are no multiple banners for each notification.

UILocalNotification *notification = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
notification.fireDate = particularfiredate;
notification.soundName = [arrayAIFFFiles objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]];
notification.alertBody = alarmname;
notification.userInfo = dicttext;

[[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification];
totalDuration = totalDuration + [[arraySoundDuration objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]]floatValue];

while (totalDuration<30) {//while time is less than 30 secs, which is the desired time.
     NSDate *newDate1 = [particularfiredate dateByAddingTimeInterval:totalDuration];
    UILocalNotification *notification1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
    notification1.fireDate = newDate1;
    notification1.soundName = [arrayAIFFFiles objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]];
    //    notification1.alertBody = alarmname;//create notification without alert body, just with the sound file, so there are no multiple banners.
    notification1.userInfo = dicttext;

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:notification1];
    totalDuration = totalDuration + [[arraySoundDuration objectAtIndex:[arraysoundfilesnames indexOfObject:particularringtone]]floatValue];

}
totalDuration = 0;
}
```